# Start epiphany browser from bash and continue script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to start my epiphany browser in a shell script and let the script do 
sth other while browser starts. The Problem i got, the browser is running in the bash window and shows me messages what it blocked etc.
The rest of the script is not executed.

I already tryed this:

`epiphany --new-tab www.google.de > /dev/null 2>&1 $`

But this only hides the output and the script is not going forward.

How can i get the browser to open and the script to go on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character to allow a command to run in the background is `&`, not `$`.

```
epiphany --new-tab www.google.de > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```